# Memory error when appending to list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, memory-management, web-scraping

I have a list of 8000 website urls. I would like to scrape the text off of the websites and save everything as a csv file. To do this i wanted to save each text-page in a list. This is my code so far which is producing and "MemoryError".

```
import os
from splinter import *
import csv
import re
from inscriptis import get_text
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException


executable_path = {'executable_path' :'./phantomjs'}
browser = Browser('phantomjs', **executable_path)
links = []


with open('./Hair_Salons.csv') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in spamreader:
        for r in row:
            links.append(r)

for l in links:
    if 'yelp' in l:
        links.remove(l)

df = []

for k in links:
    temp = []
    temp2 = []
    browser.visit(k)

    if len(browser.find_link_by_partial_text('About'))>0:
        about = browser.find_link_by_partial_text('About')
        print(about['href'])
        try:
            browser.visit(about['href'])
            temp.append(get_text(browser.html)) # <----- This is where the error is occuring
        except WebDriverException:
            pass
    else:
        browser.visit(k)
        temp.append(get_text(browser.html))
    for s in temp:
        ss = re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', s)
        temp2.append(ss)

    temp2 = ' '.join(temp2)
    print(temp2.strip())

    df.append(temp2.strip())

with open('Hair_Salons text', 'w') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(df)
```

How can i avoid getting a memory error?

Comment: Send the data to a file during the loop rather than saving it all to later

Comment: @doctorlove how would i do that? I have tried it, but seem to overwrite my file each time the loop loops.

Comment: You should be clearing your "browser = Browser('phantomjs', **executable_path)" every time you move on to the next site.  Something like "driver.quit()".  This is likely your memory issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't hold all your data in memory, then don't.
At a high level, your code has this structure

```
for k in links:
    temp = []
    temp2 = []
    browser.visit(k)

    # do stuff that fills in temp

    for s in temp:
        ss = re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', s)
        temp2.append(ss)

    temp2 = ' '.join(temp2)
    print(temp2.strip())

    df.append(temp2.strip())

with open('Hair_Salons text', 'w') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(df)
```

So, you put lots of stuff into a data frame, then write it - you don't use it in the loop. Instead of the `df.append(temp2.strip())` write to the file there. 
Make you you either open the file once, outside the loop (perhaps more sensible) or open for appending (using `'a'` instead of `'w'`).

Comment: I think i understand, however the file isn't being opened everytime the loop runs as of now does it? I was of the impression that it opens one time, once all text is in df. The memory issue seems to be at temp.append(get_text(browser.html))

Comment: That is correct - you seem to open the file once, after (trying to) read all the data into memory. I am suggesting opening it, once, before the loop to read data and writing one line at a time. Or possibly re-opening in the loop but that's a bit daft.

Comment: Alright, i will try when i come home, and accept this if it works!